# Retornar o maior valor dentre colunas e o ID referente a linha desse maior valor

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, select

Digamos que eu tenha duas colunas na minha tabela, coluna A e B.

```
+-----+-----+-----+
|  ID |  A  |  B  |
+-----+-----+-----+
|  1  | 500 | 681 |
+-----+-----+-----+
|  2  | 980 | 101 |
+-----+-----+-----+
|  3  | 110 | 981 |
+-----+-----+-----+
```

Se eu fizer o seguinte select, consigo retornar o maior valor

```
select GREATEST(MAX(A), MAX(B)) as bigger FROM valores
```

No exemplo acima o valor `981` retorna do select.
No entanto eu gostaria de retornar também o ID referente a linha que possui o maior valor. Estou fazendo o seguinte select:

```
select valor.*, GREATEST(MAX(A), MAX(B)) as bigger FROM valores as valor
```

Ele ainda me retorna o valor `981`, mas ele não me retorna o ID da linha que possui o maior valor, e sim o ID da primeira linha do banco de dados.

> Então como fazer o select para que o mesmo retorne o maior valor dentre as colunas e o ID referente a linha desse maior valor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Até consigo pensar em uma solução mas seria gambiarra, não sei se atende (por usar `union` não terá uma performance tão boa assim, dependendo da quantidade de dados):

```
SELECT id, val FROM
(SELECT id, a AS val FROM valores
UNION ALL
SELECT id, b AS val FROM valores) tmp_valores
ORDER BY val desc
LIMIT 1;
```

Criei um [fiddle](https://rextester.com/RMHW79731) também pra validar, caso queira.

Comment: Pode ser gambiarra como você disse, mas confesso que não entendo muito de select mais elaborados, no entanto a tua solução fez exatamente o que era preciso.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT campoid,campovalor
FROM TABELA
ORDER BY campovalor ASC
LIMIT 1
```

o código acima, seleciona `id` e `valor`, definindo que vai ordenar do maior para o menor valor, porém se limita a um registro.